# how to make inline update?

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have a table of products (data pulled from SQL database) with this fields: ID, Name, Price.

After i pulled the data i have a QTY cell for each product...

I want to make a cell at the bottom to sum all the qty*prodcut price to get total price of the order...

That's my table:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
</tr>
<form action="sendorder.php?supid=<?php echo $supid; ?>" method="post">  
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $prodname = $row['name'];
    $supid = $row['supplier'];
    $prodid = $row['id'];
    $prodprice = $row['price'];
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="prod[]" id="prod[<?php echo $prodid; ?>]" value="<?php echo $prodid; ?>">
            <label for="prod[<?php echo $prodid; ?>]"><?php echo $prodname; ?></label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo number_format($prodprice, 2); ?><label for="prod[<?php echo $prodid; ?>]"> NIS</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="prod[<?php echo $prodid; ?>]"><input style="font-size: 12px;" type="text" name="qty_<?php echo $prodid; ?>" placeholder="Qty" minlength="1" maxlength="3" size="2"></label>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
    <td><b>Total Price:</b></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="2">XXX NIS</td> \\ HERE I WANT TO MAKE THE LIVE CALCLUTION
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="3">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular abusive replies does not make a sense, anyway he needs help with his current code, you could guide him to the right place to get his answer instead of that, i think we are here to help each other,

Comment: I see your PHP/HTML, but I don't see your attempt at solving the problem. You should try posting the javascript that you have tried to create but couldn't get to work.

Comment: @BurhamB.Soliman This question is typical of so many questions here. The OP has posted something which he may or may not have produced himself, and asked a question that shows no effort whatsoever. It is a requirement of this site that askers have made an honest attempt to solve their problem before they ask. Without that requirement the site risks descending into a code-writing free-for-all that doesn't mesh with the site's objectives.

Comment: you need to use jquery to call the result of the selected price and multiply it by the quantity .. so u could give it a try and do some search about jquery or javascript, and if you failed u can show up wt u tried and we would help you to solve it, here is a ref about [jquery selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) , goodluck

Comment: Tangentially Perpendicular i dont want anyone to wrtie my code, i just want help... link to somewhere or some help... maybe i wasn't clear but that's only what i wanted... some help... any way iposted the solution for what i wanted, tnx!

Answer (score 1):

tnx for everyone, i found this [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/qEy3L/5/)
and that's excatly what i was looking for.

```
    function getTotal(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.sum').each(function(){
        total += parseFloat(this.innerHTML)
    });
    $('#total').text(total);
}

getTotal();

$('.qty').keyup(function(){
    var parent = $(this).parents('tr');
    var price = $('.price', parent);
    var sum = $('.sum', parent);
    var value = parseInt(this.value) * parseFloat(price.get(0).innerHTML||0);
    sum.text(value);
    getTotal();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

add `$sum = 0;` variable before `while` and put `$sum += $row['price'];` inside your `while` you can access `$sum` in Total Price `<td>`.
maybe you need `int` cast for `$row['price']`.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Qty</td>
</tr>
<form action="sendorder.php?supid=<?php echo $supid; ?>" method="post">  
<?php
$sum = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $prodname = $row['name'];
    $supid = $row['supplier'];
    $prodid = $row['id'];
    $prodprice = $row['price'];
    $sum += $row['price'];
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="prod[]" id="prod[<?php echo $prodid; ?>]" value="<?php echo $prodid; ?>">
            <label for="prod[<?php echo $prodid; ?>]"><?php echo $prodname; ?></label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo number_format($prodprice, 2); ?><label for="prod[<?php echo $prodid; ?>]"> NIS</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="prod[<?php echo $prodid; ?>]"><input style="font-size: 12px;" type="text" name="qty_<?php echo $prodid; ?>" placeholder="Qty" minlength="1" maxlength="3" size="2"></label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><b>Total Price:</b></td>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="2"><?php echo $sum; ?></td> \\ HERE I WANT TO MAKE THE LIVE CALCLUTION
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="1" colspan="3">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </td>
</tr>
</form>
```

Comment: This doesn't take into consideration the qty input that will be used AFTER the php is generated and sent to the browser.